# Why the debugger will not hit breakpoints in visual studio 2002

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2002

Now im working on visual studio 2002 framework 1.0
breakpoint is not hitting.

I confirmed  in webconfig
rebuilded my solution many times.
may i need to reset iis. 
i want valid reason why break point is not hitting?

is it possible to put breakpoints on usercontrol and debug?

when i click the link in user control it should move to next page, it shows the redirected link in url, but not able to load the page so that i trying to find the where the problem by putting break points but break point is not working.

Comment: Please provide much more detail.  Did you attach the debugger?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug?

Comment: when i click the link in user control it should move to next page, it shows the redirected link in url, but not able to load the page so that i trying to find the where the problem by putting break points but break point is not working.

Comment: Okay, but what exactly are you trying to debug? C# app, C++ app, dll, COM object, C# web service, C# Windows service, something else? You mentioned URLs and redirection. I don't know what technology are you working in.

Comment: i want to debug the c# application

Answer (score 0):

One reason would be that you are trying to debug a DLL, but that DLL is not even loaded.

Second reason is that .pdb file does not match with .exe (or .dll) file. You may think that a rebuild would solve this problem, but it could be that you are still using the wrong exe (or dll).

Third reason is that you are trying to debug in the wrong debugging mode. There are native mode, managed mode, and mixed (native + managed) mode. And there's also script mode (for VB scripts, but I never needed that). So, if breakpoint is set in native code, and debugger is in managed mode, then breakpoint will never be hit.

For all three reasons breakpoint symbol will appear as empty (hollow), which is a message from Visual Studio to you that something is wrong.

If breakpoint symbol is full circle then the code can be reached, but if breakpoint is not hit then it's the problem in the code, not in Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you for your comments, i ill check and get back to you.